# How do I find the parent URL on a webpage (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, slug

I am working on a website for a company right now and I am running into this issue:

The original URL is similar to this: `mysite.com/industrial/` where `industrial` has 4 subcategories which each have 2-6 pages within them. I changed the original URL to `mysite.com/products/` but the subcategories and pages within are not changing to include `products` in their URL - they still use `industrial`.

*For ex.:* `mysite.com/industrial/abc/` should be `mysite.com/products/abc/` but it stays as `mysite.com/industrial/abc/` after I made my change.

I assume that the subcategories are in a folder called industrial (I did not create this website so I do not know), however I can't *find* that folder anywhere and I'm not sure where to look. I have tried to go in to each of the subcategories and change their URLs, but I can only edit the `abc` part of the URL and I can't touch the rest.

** This was all done on Wordpress with a custom theme created by another company. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

**EDIT:** For anyone who is also struggling this problem this is how I solved it:

- Go to Plugins -> Plugin Editor
- At the top there was an option called "Select plugin to edit" -> chose the one that is custom to your website
- I found the information that was suggested by Phil in the comment section on [this website](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/)
- I updated the names of my fields in the rewrite permastruct section for `register_post_type` as well as `register_taxonomy`
- Update the page and flush your permalinks and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what is the defined slug when registering the custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a new Custom Post is added through a plugin or them, then the  permalinks needs to be flushed.

In the WordPress admin area, go to “Settings > Permalinks”. Click “Save Changes”. The permalinks and rewrite rules are now flushed.

Comment: Check what is the defined slug when registering the custom post type.

Comment: Yes that was it! Thank you so much for your help. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as the solution :)